# Valgrind massif - inverse ignore?

Tags: valgrind, massif

Is there a parameter in valgrind massif that allows me to only track allocations made by certain functions and classes? I would like to make a run that only traces (de)allocations made by std::vector.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Using the option --xtree-memory=full, you might be able to visualise the stacktraces that are interesting you.

See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.xtree for more details.

Comment: Another suggestion: What if I disable malloc etc. and set the function that allocates strings as allocation function via --alloc-fns? Is disabling malloc possible?

Comment: I do not think you can tell massif to ignore malloc etc.  I think you can tell massif to ignore malloc calls when called from a function to ignore, but that it looks different of ignoing malloc itself.  But the best is to try just in case I misread the manual.